# JasperSoft iReport Designer does not open when using only Java from Oracle, not Apple

Tags: macos, applications, java

In my OS X Mavericks I did not install Java 6 from Apple, just Java 8 from Oracle, and everything (including Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA) works fine, except JasperSoft iReport Designer, that just closes after you request to open it.

When trying to open from command line, using

```
open /Applications/Jaspersoft\ iReport\ Designer.app
```

I got:

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Applications/Jaspersoft iReport Designer.app.
```

After doing some research, it showed that maybe I could not have some dynlib on same place as Apple's Java have, or even using `--jdkhome=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home`, but even doing those workarounds it didn't work.

After some more research, found

```
/Applications/Jaspersoft iReport Designer.app/Contents/Resources/ireport/etc/ireport.conf
```

And inside it, changed:

```
# default location of JDK/JRE, can be overridden by using --jdkhome <dir> switch
#jdkhome="/path/to/jdk"
jdkhome="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

Now I can see the splash screen! It suggests that I could use `--jdkhome`, which I did, but it is possible that I did it the wrong way...
Anyway, just after the splash, the app closes again. Nothing is printed in terminal, but in console app I have:

```
30/09/14 22:02:39,663 com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[252]: ([0x0-0x24024].Jaspersoft iReport Designer[866]) Exited with code: 2
```

What else can I try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this [Running iReport on OS/X with Oracle JDK7](https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/803291/running-ireport-osx-oracle-jdk7)  may be telling you that it isn't compatible with Oracle's Java.

You can download the last OS X Java release (see [Java for OS X 2014-001](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572)) which is usable on OS X 10.7/.8/.9.

It appears you could then use jdkhome to point to the Apple Java release.

Comment: You're right. We need to install Apple's Java, and now everything works fine, also on Yosemite, which don't install Apple's Java by default.